# Should I lift up both sides if I only want to change one side's strut?

Tags: toyota, struts, highlander, jack-stand

I want to replace the bearing of one of my highlander's front struts. But I am not sure if it is needed to lift up and put the stands under both front sides of the vehicle to replace only one strut or I can do it by just lifting up the side I want to change the strut?

My second question is, most of the jack stands have a flat or low curved head to put the car upon them, but the cars have protruding edges around them with the height of 1 inch or more. Won't this cause a damage if I try to put the stands below them?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> My second question is, most of the jack stands have a flat or low curved head to put the car upon them, but the cars have protruding edges around them with the height of 1 inch or more. Won't this cause a damage if I try to put the stands below them?

You can get slotted rubber adapters that you put on top of the jack-stand, the look something like this:

[image: Slotted jack stand adapter]

They aren't generally expensive and then allow you to fit the jack-stand under the chassis frame rail in the same way as the factory scissor jack does.

This is how the [service manual](http://www.tohighlander.com/vehicle_lift_and_support_locations-360.html) suggests doing it.

If you're using rigid stands and a trolley jack for the actual lifting then the jacking point(s) are like so:

[image: Jacking Points]

You're probably wonder how you do this if you're using the scissor jack to lift - and the answer really is that you **don't**. Jacking/support points are where they are for good reasons.

There's *probably* a suitable point to place the stands as-is somewhere on the subframe (which obviously would allow you to lift from the jacking point using the scissor) - but I don't know Highlanders well enough to know where that would be and, well, this is not a good area for experimentation.

Lifting and supporting 1800kg+ of car to do work on it is something that when it goes wrong you consider yourself lucky if that outcome is just expensive and not life-threatening!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I use bottle jacks. I also like to know, should I lift up both sides or just the side I want to replace the strut?

Comment: @GoodMan I would.. lift and stand it at the front as per the diagram, make sure you chock the rear wheels and it should be nice and stable.

Answer (score 0):

Work the side you need, don’t waste time on the side not being changed unless you need to check the brakes etc.

As for those stands then you can add blocks to spread the load or find suitable points on the subframe etc

Some will put a bar across the full width of the car so the stands are further apart - gives better access and use blocks as needed.

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in my first question and have corrected it by now.

Comment: @GoodMan my answer still stands, even though you changed your question.